How to find the impact force needed to break an object?
How would I find the impact force needed to break an object?

Properties of the object material

What do you want to destroy?

You'd link the impact force to a stress state in the material and then link that stress state to a failure criterion. What are you ultimately trying to do?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I’m aware of tests in safety standards that require a minimum level of impact resistance. But these tests usually don’t involve testing to failure. Individual manufacturers, on the other hand, often conduct tests of to failure of their own.
There are standardized tests on the impact resistance of particular materials used in the manufacture of products. These tests are intended for comparing the impact resistance of different materials under the same standardized test. The main value of these tests is when a manufacturer is considering using a new material to compare its performance to a material already being used with good field experience.
One example of a standardized impact test is this:
https://www.astm.org/d5420-21.html
Hope this helps.

This is best done experimentally. By breaking the object by an impact and measuring the required force.

Quite true but ig, not helpful to OP.

On a microscopic level: when we break something into, say, two pieces, we create brand new fresh surface area where those two pieces were once joined. Because it takes a certain specific amount of energy to create that new surface area, that creation process (call it crack propagation) requires work be expended. So we are talking not about force but instead energy and work.
If the amount of energy available to drive the process exceeds the energy cost of the surface area creation, then the crack will self-propagate. See Shackelford's materials science text for more information on this.
